# .htaccess Rewrite URL with a query string

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have tried a ton of solutions posted at stackoverflow but nothing seems to work for me. I would like to rewrite a few URLs on my site to be search engine friendly.

I would like a URL like this:-
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?filter=accounts
To display as:-
http://www.mysite.com/accounts

A lot of posts around the web give this as the solution:-

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?filter=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But this doesn't do anything.

My site is a Joomla CMS site and there are already some rewrites within the .htaccess file. Could it be that I am putting my new RewriteRule is the wrong place?

Here is the full .htaccess file without my new RewriteRule added

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# prevents people from accessing anything with phpMyAdmin
RewriteRule phpMyAdmin - [F]

# force canonical www if request is for non-www or has port number etc
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.mysite\.com)?$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Now is tested. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-=_?]+)/?$ index.php?filter=$1 [L]
```

**.htaccess** goes in root directory.

The requested URL is *http://www.mysite.com/accounts/* but could be anything: *http://www.mysite.com/apples/*.

NOTE: The URL displayed in the address bar is the one that was entered in that address bar. I assume is not *http://www.mysite.com/index.php?filter=accounts* because I guess the purpose of the redirection is to replace it with a more friendly one (*http://www.mysite.com/accounts*), which is the one that has to be typed in the address bar, not the other way around. Little confusing but I hope it makes sense.

To test it, include the following only code at index.php in root directory.

```
<?php 

if ($_GET['filter'] == 'accounts') {
echo "This is Accounts<br /><br />";    
}else {
echo "This is INDEX<br /><br />";       
}

?>
```

As to where to place the rewrite rules inside .htaccess, I could not know. I guess you have to try it before and after the actual rules.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it doesn't do anything. The query string could be one of several options and won't always be 'accounts' although if I get a solution to work for a single query there aren't that many that I couldn't add a line for each one.

Comment: Well, I will try and TEST a similar solution. There is one, I am sure. It is important the .htaccess file is in root directory: public_html in this case.

Comment: Hi. The .htaccess is in the public_html and I have just cleared caches just to make sure that there isn't a caching issue stopping it working.

Comment: Hi Felipe. I really appreciate your efforts trying to help me out but I still can't get this to work. I wonder if what you have suggested is the opposite of what in need to happen. I need the requested URL to be http://www.mysite.com/index.php?filter=accounts so that I can use the query string in PHP but I would like the URL that is displayed in the browser address bar to read http://www.mysite.com/accounts or if that isn't possible the it could be http://www.mysite.com/services/accounts or http://www.mysite.com/services/applies, etc. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Felipe. Got there in the end. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks @FelipeAlamedaA. What about two parameters? Like: http://example.com/accounts/applets