# I want to remove a string with a question mark at the end of my URL with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove the string

```
?mobile=1
```

out from different URLs with `.htaccess`. So:

`https://www.example.com/?mobile=1` should become `https://www.example.com/`

and

`https://www.example.com/something/?mobile=1` should become `https://www.example.com/something/`

I tried the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)?mobile=1 /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

But that does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: This question already has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592535/htaccess-rewrite-url-with-a-query-string

Comment: I tried the following but that did not work:

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-=_?]+)/?$ ?mobile=1 [L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.+)?mobile=1 /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only, which notably excludes the query string. So the above would *never* match. (Unless there was a %-encoded `?` in the URL-path, eg. `%3F`)

To match the query string you need an additional *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) and match against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

The regex `.+` (1 or more) will not match the document root (ie. your first example: `https://www.example.com/?mobile=1`). You need to allow for an *empty* URL-path in this case. eg. `.*` (0 or more).

For example, try the following near the *top* of your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =mobile=1
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

This matches the query string `mobile=1` exactly, case-sensitive (as in your examples). No other URL parameters can exist. The `=` prefix on the *CondPattern* makes this an exact match string comparison, rather than a regex as it normally would.

And redirects to the same URL-path, represented by the `$1` backreference in the *substitution* string that contains the URL-path from the captured group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag removes the query string from the redirect response.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect and and only change to a 301 (permanent) - if that is the intention - once you have confirmed this works as intended. 301s are cached persistently by the browser so can make testing problematic.

Comment: You are awesome!!!

Your code

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =mobile=1
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [QSD,R=301,L]

worked perfectly!